# Using a prvalue to create a shared_pointer

Tags: c++, move, shared-ptr

I have a class functionCombiner which constructor looks like this

```
FunctionCombiner::FunctionCombiner(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction>> Inner_) : Inner(std::move(Inner_)), valuationFunction("", 0) //<- Needs to initalize itself even though it gets all data from inner functions.
{
}
```

In my main class I'm calling it like this:

```
vector<std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction>> combinedStillFrontFunctions{ stillFrontStock, stillFrontEuropeanCall };
std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction> StillFrontFunctions = std::make_shared<FunctionCombiner>(combinedStillFrontFunctions);
```

What I would like to be able to do is reduce that to one line by constructing it in place like so

```
std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction> StillFrontFunctions = std::make_shared<FunctionCombiner>({ stillFrontStock, stillFrontEuropeanCall });
```

Which the compiler doesn't like. Is there a way to make this work? This works obviously:

```
FunctionCombiner StillFrontFunctions({ stillFrontStock, stillFrontEuropeanCall });
```

But I need it to be a shared pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Shorting some names to make the example readable w/o horizontal scrollbars.  You should consider doing the same...)

Passing `{x,y}` to `make_shared()` is attempting to forward a brace-enclosed initializer list, not to initialize the value in the shared pointer, but the temporary object its constructor takes.  It's not something that can be forwarded since it's not a full expression on its own.  So make a temporary vector with those values:

```
... = make_shared<FunComb>(vector<shared_ptr<valFun>>{FS, FEC});
```

Another approach may be to change `FunComb`'s constructor to be a (or add a new) variadic constructor, removing the need to pass in a `vector` just to hold the inputs.

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick! Touching upon your first paragraph, this certainly makes the lines comically large. A completely separate question (only if you will) but how could/should you make that more readable?

`std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction> USTreasuryFunctions = std::make_shared<FunctionCombiner>(vector<std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction>>{ USTreasuryBond, USDIRS, stillFrontEuropeanCall, StorytelAmericanCall });`

Comment: Try [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) aliases, eg: `using valuationFunctionPtr = std::shared_ptr<valuationFunction>; using valuationFunctionPtrVec = std::vector<valuationFunctionPtr>; auto USTreasuryFunctions = std::make_shared<FunctionCombiner>(valuationFunctionPtrVec{ USTreasuryBond, USDIRS, stillFrontEuropeanCall, StorytelAmericanCall });`

Comment: Or, like Chris said, make `FunctionCombiner`'s constructor take variadic parameters instead of a `vector` (or maybe `std::initialization_list<valuationFunctionPtr>`), then `auto USTreasuryFunctions = std::make_shared<FunctionCombiner>({ USTreasuryBond, USDIRS, stillFrontEuropeanCall, StorytelAmericanCall });` should work